# Share button on website not working for LinkedIn but working for Facebook & Twitter

Tags: metadata, share-button

I have noticed an issue when attempting to share content from my company website to LinkedIn. I have referred this to my website agency but they have suggesting contacting LinkedIn who referred me here!

When the share button is selected for LinkedIn on any page of our website the share box will appear but the meta content from my website does not pull through. Example page: https://www.dwf.law/Sectors/Real-Estate#sectorTab=how-can-we-help-tab

When the url is placed directly into LinkedIn the meta image and data will pull through as expected.

It is only when using the 'share' buttons on any page of our website that the meta content does not pull through.  Can you advise if there is anything we need to change in the settings of our website to fix this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can share your data on LinkedIn using this code.

```
< a class="w-inline-block social-share-btn lnk" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=&title=&summary=&source=" target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn" onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title)); return false;">< /a>
```

I haven't test it but it should work.